# Prestashop - Add additional fields on product combination

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to add additional fields on my product combinations in order to have custom meta titles for the combinations.
So I created this module:

**My module definition:**

```php
class CombinationCustomFields extends Module
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'combinationcustomfields';
        $this->tab = 'administration';
        $this->author = '';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Combination Custom Fields');
        $this->description = $this->l('Add additional fields on combinations');
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7.1', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    }

    public function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install() || !$this->_installSql()
            || !$this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsCombinationBottom')
            || !$this->registerHook('actionAttributeCombinationSave')
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall() && $this->_unInstallSql();
    }

    /**
     * Add database fields
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _installSql()
    {
        $sqlInstall = "ALTER TABLE " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "product_attribute "
            . "ADD meta_title_fr VARCHAR(255) NULL, "
            . "ADD meta_title_en VARCHAR(255) NULL;";

        $returnSql = Db::getInstance()->execute($sqlInstall);

        return $returnSql;
    }

    /**
     * Remove database fields
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _unInstallSql()
    {
        $sqlInstall = "ALTER TABLE " . _DB_PREFIX_ . "product_attribute "
            . "DROP meta_title_fr, "
            . "DROP meta_title_en";

        $returnSql = Db::getInstance()->execute($sqlInstall);

        return $returnSql;
    }

    public function hookDisplayAdminProductsCombinationBottom($params)
    {
        $combination = new Combination($params['id_product_attribute']);
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'id_product_attribute' => $params['id_product_attribute'],
                'meta_title_fr' => $combination->meta_title_fr,
                'meta_title_en' => $combination->meta_title_en,
            )
        );


        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/combinationfields.tpl');
    }


    public function hookActionAttributeCombinationSave($params)
    {
        $combination = new Combination($params['id_product_attribute']);
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'id_product_attribute' => $params['id_product_attribute'],
                'meta_title_fr' => $combination->meta_title_fr,
                'meta_title_en' => $combination->meta_title_en,
            )
        );

        $combination->meta_title_fr = Tools::getValue('meta_title_fr');
        $combination->meta_title_en = Tools::getValue('meta_title_en');

        $combination->save();

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/combinationfields.tpl');

    }
}
```

**My HTML for the admin hook:**

```html
<div class="m-b-1 m-t-1">
    <h2>{l s='Combination Custom Fields' mod='combinationcustomfields'}</h2>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-4">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="combination_{$id_product_attribute}_attribute_meta_title_fr">{l s='Meta title FR' mod='combinationcustomfields'}</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="combination_{$id_product_attribute}[attribute_meta_title_fr]" id="combination_{$id_product_attribute}_attribute_meta_title_fr" type="text" value="{if $meta_title_fr != ''}{$meta_title_fr}{/if}">
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-4">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="combination_{$id_product_attribute}_attribute_meta_title_en">{l s='Meta title EN' mod='cmp_combination_customfields'}</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="combination_{$id_product_attribute}[attribute_meta_title_en]" id="combination_{$id_product_attribute}_attribute_meta_title_en" type="text" value="{if $meta_title_en != ''}{$meta_title_en}{/if}">
            <br />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**My override of the combination class:**

```php
class Combination extends CombinationCore
{
    public $meta_title_fr;
    public $meta_title_en;
    /**
     * @see ObjectModel::$definition
     */
    public static $definition = [
        'table' => 'product_attribute',
        'primary' => 'id_product_attribute',
        'fields' => [
            'id_product' => ['type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'shop' => 'both', 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true],
            'location' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isGenericName', 'size' => 64],
            'ean13' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isEan13', 'size' => 13],
            'isbn' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isIsbn', 'size' => 32],
            'upc' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isUpc', 'size' => 12],
            'mpn' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isMpn', 'size' => 40],
            'quantity' => ['type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isInt', 'size' => 10],
            'reference' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 64],
            'supplier_reference' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 64],
            'meta_title_fr' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 64],
            'meta_title_en' => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'size' => 64],

            /* Shop fields */
            'wholesale_price' => ['type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isPrice', 'size' => 27],
            'price' => ['type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isNegativePrice', 'size' => 20],
            'ecotax' => ['type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isPrice', 'size' => 20],
            'weight' => ['type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isFloat'],
            'unit_price_impact' => ['type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isNegativePrice', 'size' => 20],
            'minimal_quantity' => ['type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isUnsignedId', 'required' => true],
            'low_stock_threshold' => ['type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'shop' => true, 'allow_null' => true, 'validate' => 'isInt'],
            'low_stock_alert' => ['type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isBool'],
            'default_on' => ['type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'allow_null' => true, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isBool'],
            'available_date' => ['type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'shop' => true, 'validate' => 'isDateFormat'],
        ],
    ];

}
```

But when I save the product, the fields are in the request:

[image: Fields]

But I have a 400 Error:

[image: Error]

Any idea of my mistake here ?

All the best and thanks in advance for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the **combination class** using an override controler:

```
class Combination extends CombinationCore
{
    public $newVariableName;

    public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null)
    {
        Combination::$definition['fields']['newVariableName'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAnything', 'required' => false);
        parent::__construct($id, $id_lang, $id_shop);
    }
}
```

You will also need to override `product.php`

```
public function updateProductAttribute($id_product_attribute, ..., $newVariableName = null){

public function addCombinationEntity($wholesale_price, ..., $newVariableName = null){
```

and so on...

Comment: It's way much cleaner indeed !!
But still have the error "This form should not contain extra fields.", Any idea ?

Comment: I see that on PS 1.6, there was a lot of file to override (Product, ProductController,AdminProductsController, product.js...) is it still the case in 1.7 ?

Comment: Yeah you also need to override your product.php page in order to be able to save, edit ect ...

Answer (score 0):

I would do so:

HTML:
Change all attributes **combination_** to **custom_**

```
<div class="m-b-1 m-t-1">
<h2>{l s='Combination Custom Fields' mod='combinationcustomfields'}</h2>
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-4">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="custom_{$id_product_attribute}_attribute_meta_title_fr">{l s='Meta title FR' mod='combinationcustomfields'}</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="custom_{$id_product_attribute}[attribute_meta_title_fr]" id="custom_{$id_product_attribute}_attribute_meta_title_fr" type="text" value="{if $meta_title_fr != ''}{$meta_title_fr}{/if}">
        <br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-4">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="custom_{$id_product_attribute}_attribute_meta_title_en">{l s='Meta title EN' mod='cmp_combination_customfields'}</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="custom_{$id_product_attribute}[attribute_meta_title_en]" id="custom_{$id_product_attribute}_attribute_meta_title_en" type="text" value="{if $meta_title_en != ''}{$meta_title_en}{/if}">
        <br />
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Next step:

```
public function hookActionAttributeCombinationSave($params)
{
    $id_product_attribute = $params['id_product_attribute'];
    $custom = $_POST['custom_' . $id_product_attribute];

    ....
}
```